# Import CSV with different delimiter separating columns and records, delimiter found in one column

Tags: csv, import, sas

Hello I was wondering if it is possible to import a csv where: 
a.) records are not separated by anything
b.) a column is a sentence which may or may not contain commas

To illustrate, this is the content of the csv file:

```
Att1,Att2,Att3dog,brown,I, a dogcat,yellow,I, a cat
```

I want to import it so that is looks like a sas data set similar to below:

```
| Att1 | Att2   | Att3      |
| dog  | brown  | I, a dog  |
| cat  | yellow | I, a cat  |
```

Unfortunately, as I am not the direct recipient of the data, I don't know why the csv file ended up this way.

For reference, this is the proc import script I ran to try:

```
  proc import 
         datafile="path/have.csv" out=want dbms = csv replace; 
         delimiter=","; 
         getnames=yes; 
  run;
```

Is this possible, or do I have to edit the csv file itself? Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Comment: You cannot separate by comma and end up with a comma in the value. Unless there are quotes around the value in the original file.  Are you sure there is not anything between the records? Perhaps it is just not a printable character.  Look at the hex codes of the file.  Many editors allow this. In SAS you can use the $HEX format to display the hexadecimal values of the characters in a string.  Characters like '00'x or 'FF'x might not be evident in the way you are currently reading the file.

Comment: Your data doesn't even have a delimiter between att3 and dog? How are you viewing the file? Use notepad++ or your choice of text editor and select show invisible characters to see if there's some kind of delimiter.